# Nginx not listening on port 443 (MacOs) - If I change the port from 443 to 8443, starts listening but doesn't work

Tags: php, macos, ssl, nginx

I have Nginx 1.19.2 + php-fpm on MacOs Catalina.

I have only two servers with ssl enable. Both of them listening port 443:

```
user _www staff;
worker_processes 1;

server{
    ...
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/shop.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/shop.key;

    server_name my.app.com;

    root /Path/to/root/app;
    ...
}

server{
    ...
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/shop.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/shop.key;

    server_name other.app.com;

    root /Path/to/root/app;
    ...
}
```

Result of command nmap 127.0.0.1 **(There's no port 443)**

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-09-06 19:09 CEST

Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000068s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
3306/tcp open  mysql
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
9000/tcp open  cslistener
```

When I try to access the site it doesn't work. Nothing on the logs!

If I change to one of the sites from 443 to 8443 it works.

```
...
user _www staff;
worker_processes 1;
...
server{
    ...
    listen 8443 ssl http2;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/shop.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/shop.key;

    server_name my.app.com;

    root /Path/to/root/app;
    ...
}

server{
    ...
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/shop.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/shop.key;

    server_name other.app.com;

    root /Path/to/root/app;
    ...
}
```

Result of command nmap 127.0.0.1 **(Now the port 443 appears on nmap!)**

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-09-06 19:21 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000058s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8443/tcp open  https-alt
9000/tcp open  cslistener
```

Maybe something related to:
opening ports ?
user running nginx ?
MacOs config/firewall ?

Starting nginx with: "sudo nginx"

I would like to have the correct configuration and understand it, not just some hack.

I'm really lost here, any help is appreciated!

Thanks !

Comment: *"Nothing on the logs!"* - in which logs did you look?

Comment: the logs I set:

`access_log /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/access.log;
error_log /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/error.log;`

Should I look somewhere else?

Comment: I would expect relevant information to be in the `error_log` or on stderr when you start nginx, Are there really no data in the logs (and on stderr) at all or do you only think that these are not relevant to your question?

Comment: there's nothing in the logs at all.
nginx -t command says everything is ok.
starting nginx produces no error.

Comment: Running:   sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
`php-fpm   12685         truads   10u  IPv4 0xb82f25c61a58d2f5      0t0  TCP localhost:9000 (LISTEN)
nginx     19849           root    7u  IPv4 0xb82f25c63867c2f5      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     19849           root    8u  IPv4 0xb82f25c61b3ff6b5      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     19850         truads    7u  IPv4 0xb82f25c63867c2f5      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     19850         truads    8u  IPv4 0xb82f25c61b3ff6b5      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
`

Comment: apparently nginx is listening to 443 but it simply does not work.

Comment: Since nmap is not accessing nginx like a real HTTPS client (especially no SNI in ClientHello, which is needed for multiple domains on the same IP address) please check with a different tool, like `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -servername my.app.com`.

Comment: openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -servername my.app.com
`connect: Connection refused
connect:errno=61`

Comment: And this is done on the same machine where nginx is running and where you also see that it is actually listening on `TCP *:443`  at the same time?

Comment: yes, everything on same machine. :/

Comment: It is strange, when I run `sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"`
I got `TCP *:443 (LISTEN)` two times:  one as `nginx root *:443` and other as`<myuser> root *:443`

Comment: This is pretty normal: nginx is started as rooted but forks worker childs to do the actual work which also run with reduced privileges. All of these have the listener sockets open. Still, it is strange that you cannot access these listeners from the same machine .